# Snowflake having Grants persist , when table re-creates every day during ETL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to 'Grant References' to a table in snowflake that gets 'create(d) or replace(d)' every morning as part of a daily ETL. So I have to run this every day to grant the right privilege to a certain role.

```
grant references on table example_table to role example_role;
```

I know the is a 'grant select on future', but this does not appear to exist for 'references'.

Anybody know the syntax or have an idea on how to get this grant to persist?
I cannot find anything in the snowflake docs.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `grant references on future tables in schema example_schema to role example_role;` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE x (i int) COPY GRANTS 


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW x COPY GRANTS 
AS 
select 1 as i
```

Keyword is **COPY GRANTS** , it should work with all ddl command having create or replace syntax, of course if object does not exists it does not copy anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this type of issues by adding the grants as part of the ETL pipeline. For better maintenance, I created a table in snowflake which has two columns, table name and the grant required on that table. I wrote a stored procedure that looks at these tables and execute the grants. The stored procedure is part of the last step in the ETL pipeline

Comment: Upvote, that's a very elegant approach, yes, it does make sense the DDL and grants to be maintained in the ETL pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake's implementation of materialized views provides a number of unique characteristics which can be helpful because materialized views can improve the performance of queries that use the same subquery results repeatedly.
OR follow the syntax of these commands which may help.
"grant create materialized view on schema mydb.myschema to role myrole;"
OR
"grant operate on warehouse report_wh to role analyst with grant option"